# Increase Global Font Size CSS

Tags: css, font-size

Is there any way to globally increase the size of a font in CSS?  When I use a particular secondary font, it natively requires a 15% boost to match the size of my primary font.

I currently have this class:

```css
.freight{
    font-family: freight-text-pro, serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size:1.15em;
}
```

which works fine as a child element, however when applying it to the parent (an extra span seems like unnecessary code), it shrinks right down, which is obviously expected behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: em cascades sizing from it's parents. If you set your body font size all cascaded (em) fonts will also be resized.

Comment: @DreamTeK, yes, but this is only required "globally" for the one font, not all.  It's a design problem more than anything, the font is just natively smaller than my primary font.

Answer (score 3):

Not really getting what you mean, but from what I'm getting.

This might be what you're looking for

```
body, html { 
font-family: freight-text-pro, serif;
font-style: normal;
font-size:1.15em; }
```

This will globally affect the fonts on every page & tag

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks but that's not what I'm after.  I want the "Freight Text Pro" font - which is the secondary font - to be 15% larger at all times, so it matches the primary font without requiring additional spans inside H2 etc (adding the class with font-size:1.15em directly on the H2 will force that size, not the standard H2 size).  I'm not sure if it's actually possible.

Comment: When I say matches, I mean is design terms, not code.  The primary font at 1em is equal to Freight Text Pro at 1.15em.

Comment: Okay. I get it now. I think what you're trying to achieve just requires use different type of CSS selector. How about you put the HTML code up there.